# php switch statement alternative syntax parse error when extra new line

Tags: php

Works as expected without parse error

```
<?php switch(rand(0,2)): ?>
<?php case 0: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php case 1: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php case 2: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php endswitch;?>
</div>
```

Produces parese error because of the new line after switch...This is very odd behavior. Using PHP 5.4.24.

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `"endswitch (T_ENDSWITCH)"' or`"case (T_CASE)"' or `"default (T_DEFAULT)"' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/phppos/index.php on line 18

```
<?php switch(rand(0,2)): ?>

<?php case 0: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php case 1: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php case 2: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php endswitch;?>
```

Comment: Tried `<?php switch(rand(0,2)) { ?> something ... <?php }?>` ?

Comment: Huh, that's kind of cool. Tried it out in hhvm and got a similar but more verbose error: $ hhvm test.php 

Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected T_INLINE_HTML, expecting T_ENDSWITCH or T_CASE or T_DEFAULT in /home/jkoudys/test.php on line 2
    #0 at [/home/jkoudys/test.php:2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything outside of `<?php...?>` - including whitespace - is output as though with echo, so this:

```
?>

<?php
```

is equivalent to this:

```
 echo '
 ';
```

Since such an echo would be invalid at that location - in a switch but not in any case or default block - it stands to reason it's invalid to imply it by closing the PHP block in that way.

The solution is simply not to close the PHP block with ?> except where you actually want output to occur.

Comment: From the docs: **The switch statement executes line by line (actually, statement by statement). In the beginning, no code is executed.** So yes echo will generate error.

Answer (score 0):

This template code with inline PHP is makes 100% no sense unless you are not showing us the full code:

```
<?php switch(rand(0,2)): ?>

<?php case 0: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php case 1: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php case 2: ?>
<?php break;?>

<?php endswitch;?>
```

Why not just do this and add a `default:` at the end to catch cases you might not find:

```
switch(rand(0,2)) {
  case 0:
    break;
  case 1:
    break;
  case 2:
    break;
  default:
}
```

Comment: Why would I need a default of rand(0,2)?

Comment: I took the code to be a simplified test case to narrow down the problem and avoid irrelevant details.